# How to Use a AjaxScript Manager on ASP.NET 3,5 to add AjaX control Toolkit Script Manager

Tags: development, ajax-control-tookit

How should I use Ajax Control Toolkit in Sharepoint 2010. When I add Extender Calendar don't Shown.  I tried add AjaxToolkitScript manager, but it's vrite me that it shouldn't be there 2 Scripts Manager on the site.

The Error shown:

**Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.**

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 has a ScriptManager added to every Master Page by default. You need to open up the Master Page you’re using and remove the existing  tag and replace it with the following Script Manager:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

Add a Script Manager in the your custom master page, then it will be available to any page referencing the master page, rather than adding references to individual pages.

Comment: And how should I open a master page in Visual Studio ? Where could I found this master page ?

Comment: To do this, open up the master page for your site.  Typically, this will be located at `<site url>/_catalogs/masterpage`. You can edit this file by opening it in an editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer, or directly in Notepad by opening your master page library via DAV (typically `\\server\<pathtosite>\_catalogs\masterpage`)

Comment: After I replecing all master pages in notepad nothing changes and CalendarExtander doesn't shown. Please Falak help.

Comment: Next controls from AjaxControl Toolkit shown. Only the CalendarExtander dont shown. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you added the reference to the assembly? `<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>` as well?

Comment: Yes I added them to the two master pages. To the v4Master.page and to the default master page. Some of controls from AjaxControlToolkit worked, but not worked Calendar Extender.

Comment: I tried javaScript to set up z-index, I tried CSS files. Meybe thats why I don't see this its that Sharepoint add a name with a Guid to the Textbox ? I look at firebug to the code and my input textbox called on site: **ctl00_m_g_d7a88705_72a3_424e_8b9c_ede0a6d8f542_ctl00_Date1**

Comment: I done by Jquery :) Here is Linq

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Answer (score 0):

I look at and find  resolution to use jQuery plugin :) Here is my solution: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default